# Convert String datetime to numeric date time

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, azure, t-sql

I have a column that I need converting from string date time to an actual data time data value.

The current format is as follows

> 15-JUN-22 10.24.10.414000

and I need to change it to the following format

> 15-06-22 10.24.10.414000

I use a stored procedure to automatically change the format, but it fails on this stage due to the non numeric characters.
Is there a way map or change all the string months to int values within the datetime? and if so how?

Converts used so far

```
TRY_CAST(CREATE_DATE AS DATETIME2(7)) AS CREATE_DATE
```

AND

```
CASE WHEN LEN([INTERVAL_START_DATE]) > 0 THEN TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME2, [INTERVAL_START_DATE], 103) ELSE NULL END
```

Comment: `15-06-22 10.24.10.414000` is **not** an "actual date time data value" - it's just another formatted date. Why aren't you storing actual `datetime2(7)` values?

Comment: Your title and content seem to conflict here. In the title you say you want to use a [numerical data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/numeric-types?view=sql-server-ver16), but the post suggests you want to use a [date and time data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#DateandTimeDataTypes). Which is it? Of course, the real question is why are you using a string based data type for a date and time value in the first place; that is a significant design flaw.

Comment: @Larnu, The reason it has been worded this way there are no posts that specifically  attempt this type of convert

Comment: This data is called from a API and don't manage the actual dataset or structures, just need to implement the convert within a sproc in order to take it from one location to another but in the right format

Comment: So what *do* you want? A numerical data type or a date and time data type? If the former, why don't you want to use a date and time data type for a **date and time** value, and please correct the post. If the latter, please correct your title.

Comment: @Larnu, the original is in string format needs it to be in datetime, because of the non-numeric month value convert and cast both fail to do this

Comment: Is it the letters of the month that are breaking it? Or the period characters delimiting the time components? Or both? Or some other combination? Seems like you should be able to convert this to `datetime2` with an appropriate input and style selection.

Comment: What year is `22`? 1922? 2022? 1822? Actually 22AD (0022)? How do *you* know, and (more importantly) how does SQL Server?

Comment: Unfortunately you will need to do a lot of work to successfully convert your strings. The closest style matching your format is 113 - but your separators will need to be changed to match that style. And yes - NEVER store 2 digit years since we learned all about why during Y2K.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
CAST({your field name} as date) CONVERT(date,'{systemClock.UtcNow.ToString("o")}',127)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.